# Order of quantifiers and the intepretation of a sequence $(a_n)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I've been struggling for the past few days with a problem related to the interpretation of a predicate when the order of the quantifiers is changed.

Predicate. A sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ is convergent if,

$$
\exists L \in \mathbb R: \forall \epsilon>0: \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N: \forall n \in \mathbb N: n>n_0 \Rightarrow \mid a_n - L\mid <\epsilon. 
$$

Assume the order of the quantifiers are changed to obtain the following predicates;

$$
\text{(a) } \exists L \in \mathbb R: \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N: \forall \epsilon>0: \forall n \in \mathbb N: n>n_0 \Rightarrow \mid a_n - L\mid <\epsilon,
$$

$$
\text{(b) } \exists L \in \mathbb R: \forall \epsilon>0: \forall n \in \mathbb N:\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N: n>n_0 \Rightarrow \mid a_n - L\mid <\epsilon, 
$$

$$
\text{(c) } \forall \epsilon>0: \exists L \in \mathbb R: \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N: \forall n \in \mathbb N: n>n_0 \Rightarrow \mid a_n - L\mid <\epsilon. 
$$

How do these changes affect the (interpretation/meaning of) sequence $(a_n)$, and what type of sequences satisfy to these predicates. More importantly, I would also appreciate some explanation about how to approach these type of problems.

Your many answers/feebacks/tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This implies the sequence converges to a limit $L$ and also constant (equal to $L$) from some $n_0$.
2. This implies the sequence has some sub-sequence that converges to some limit $L$.
3. This is equivalent to saying A sequence of real numbers ($a_n$) is convergent if...  (normal definition).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, could you be more explicit as to how you got to those conclusions? I'd like to understand the reasoning/strategy to solve these types problems. Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I'm fairly new to discrete math, and I would like build an understanding which allows me to solve these types of problems and many more. That said, in this case it's no so much about proving these predicates, but rather to understand how the order of the quantifiers change the meaning/interpretation of these predicates (and the sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: Your solution to 2. is *false*. It does _not_ imply the sequence has some subsequence that converges to some limit; in fact, the statement is true for *any* sequence $(a_n)$. This is vacuously true, since for any $n$ we can pick an $n_0$ such that $n_0  \geq n$. Also, as far as the solution to 3. goes: Yes, this statement is equivalent to the normal (i.e., original) definition. However, this isn't completely obvious (as your answer seems to suggest), and it crucially depends on the completeness of $\mathbb R$, which you didn't mention either.

Answer (score 1):

(a) This means that the sequence $(a_n)$ is constant from some $n_0$ onwards.

(b) This statement is true for *any* sequence of reals $(a_n)$. In fact it is true in a "trivial" kind of way, since for any given $n$ we can always pick an $n_0$ such that $n_0  \geq n$. (For concreteness, we can simply pick $n_0 = n$.)

(c) One can show that this statement is *equivalent* to the original definition; i.e., for $(a_n)$ a given sequence of reals, it is equivalent to the statement "$(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence". However, it is important to note that the proof of the non-trivial implication of this equivalence requires the use of the completeness of the real numbers (if instead we were talking about sequences of rational numbers, for instance, the implication wouldn't be true). The proof isn't very difficult yet also not trivial.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation that (b) is vacuously true.

Comment: An implication $A \Rightarrow B$ is ("vacuously") true if $A$ is false. In this case, $A$ would be "$n > n_0$". To show that for (b) any sequence satisfies, we can pick for $L$ any real number (for concreteness, say we pick $L = 5$); then, for any given  $\varepsilon >0$ and any $n \in \mathbb N$, we *can* find a natural number $n_0$ that makes  "$n > n_0$" false. Namely, we can pick any $n_0$ that is greater than or equal to $n$; for concreteness, we can simply pick $n_0 = n$. Note that the (accepted) answer by TheHolyJoker is wrong.

Comment: Is the sentence $\exists x \;(x>0 ⇒ 1\ne1)$ vacuously true?

Comment: True in which structure? You have to specify in which structure you want to interpret that sentence.

Comment: Say we consider the statement $\exists x \in \mathbb R \, (1 \neq 1 \Rightarrow x^2 < 0 )$ (I suspect this is the type of sentence you actually meant-correct me if I'm wrong, of course). Then this statement is, indeed, vacuously true.

Comment: I meant, do you consider $∃(>0⇒1≠1),$ in real analysis, to be vacuously true?

Comment: It's the same kind of thing as the one mentioned in (b) by OP, so I guess I do indeed. However, I understand now what you're concerned about: It really depends on what one considers to be "vacuously true" (i.e., on the precise definition that one uses). To my feeling, (b) does concern a vacuous truth. In the end, whether or not it is "vacuously" true, does not really matter; what matters is that the statement is true. Anyway, I removed the word 'vacuous' from my answer (see above). The point is that the (accepted) answer given above, is *wrong*.

Comment: Yes, I was thrown off by your apparent conflation of 'true' and 'vacuously true' (in my opinion, the latter is a universal state, so both my example and (b) are true but not *vacuously* true); thanks for editing the post! $\quad$ Your latest example $\exists x \in \mathbb R \, (1 \neq 1 \Rightarrow x^2 < 0 )$ is interesting in that—nevermind its ostensible existential quantification—its parenthetical part (the open formula) is vacuously true even without any quantification.